# Chrome reports 'Invalid Property Value' for image

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser

In an HTML doc, I have written a basic image class

```
<div class = "upper-img"></div>
```

In my CSS file, the class is simply defined as

```
.upper-img {
    width: 360px;
    height: 250px;
    background: url(C:\siteImages\alaskanMountains.jpg);
}
```

I have made sure the path is correct, and the image does indeed display properly in an HTML tag. However, I'm getting a chrome browser error saying 'invalid property value. Here's a picture for reference:

[image: Invalid property value]

I have seen several very similar questions about this on StackOverflow, but all of which seem to be fixed by changing the properties of the background element.

For example, a couple other questions have been resolved by changing

```
background-image: url("file")
```

to

```
background: url("file")
```

This clearly has not worked for me, any ideas?

Comment: Try setting your path like this: 
`background: url('file:///C:/siteImages/alaskanMountains.jpg');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, it's **recommended** that you avoid spacing when assigning a class to an HTML object, i.e:

```
<div class = "upper-img"></div>
```

should be:

```
<div class="upper-img"></div>
```

---

For the background, you have to use the relative path of the image. If the image is inside the same folder of your in-line css, you can just call the image. If it's in a different folder you need to navigate using:

../ to go back one folder level.
/ to go further one folder level.

I.E:

```
background: url(../img/alaskanMountains.jpg);
```

Comment: Where is it recommended to leave spaces out of attribute declarations? It's certainly unconventional to add spaces but I've never heard anyone suggesting to consciously avoid them.

Comment: It falls under the best practices of programming. For HTML, I highly recommend this article: https://www.webfx.com/blog/web-design/20-html-best-practices-you-should-follow/

Comment: The only bit about leaving spaces out that I can see is under minification, which is a different thing. Not a fan of that article as it hops back and forth between best practices that would apply to HTML5, and those that are relevant to XHTML 1.0 but not HTML5. For example #4 seems written in a pre-HTML5 era but #10 goes on to talk about how you should avoid using divs in HTML5. #12 is also clearly written for XHTML - because [the W3C *HTML* specification doesn't require all tags be closed, only the W3C *XHTML* spec does](https://blog.novalistic.com/archives/2017/08/optional-end-tags-in-html).

Comment: Nothing against best practices articles (about two-thirds of the stuff there is still relevant), but that particular one stands out as being dated at best (having been written primarily for XHTML 1.0) and inconsistent/self-contradicting at worst.

Comment: I ended up moving the picture into my CSS folder and it worked! Thanks a bunch, that's great to know.

Answer (score 0):

Slashes within the `background` rule should be forward, not backward. In addition, make sure you don't leave spaces between the attributes, the equal sign, and the attribute's value:

`<div class="upper-img"></div>`